# Why does the jquery fadeout not work here

Tags: jquery, hammer.js

When I swiperight (from red to green) the fadeout of red div is done Then the fadein is done of green.
When I swipeleft (from green to red) the fadeout of green div seems not to take place because div red is quickly faded in?

How can I fix that?

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var elementAlarm = document.getElementById('ContentAlarm');
        var elementMap = document.getElementById('ContentMap');

        var hammertime = Hammer(elementAlarm).on("swiperight", function (event) {
            $(elementAlarm).fadeOut(1000);
            $(elementMap).fadeIn(500);

        });

        var hammertime = Hammer(elementMap).on("swipeleft", function (event) {
            $(elementMap).fadeOut(1000);
            $(elementAlarm).fadeIn(500);
        });
    });


</script>
<div id="ContentAlarm" style="background-color: red; width: 50%; height: 100%;text-align:center;font-size:72px;">
    ALARM
</div>
<div id="ContentMap" style="background-color: green; width: 50%; height: 100%;text-align:center;font-size:72px;">
    MAP
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery effects are asynchronous. You need to use callbacks to not overlap the animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the fade functions like so:

```
$(elementMap).fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(elementAlarm).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: ah... as they are async I chain/queue them with the callback right?

Comment: That's what I'm guessing, it seemed to work in a fiddle I mocked up, but I'm not sure how the swiping motions effect it.